# ¿Cómo puedo calcular percentiles en R de los siguientes datos por hora, de múltiples csv?

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, dataframe, percentil

Buen día.

Presento el siguiente problema:

Tengo una carpeta con 20 archivos .csv que contienen la siguiente información (adjunto imagen de un .csv, pasé el texto a tabla para visualizar mejor):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán, tiene datos de temperatura por hora para diferentes días y meses, por tanto, tengo muchos datos para una misma hora.

Lo que deseo hacer es calcular los percentiles 0.05, 0.5 y 0.95 para cada hora por mes, es decir, que el agrupamiento de los datos quede algo así (adjunto un .csv completamente diferente pero que tiene la estructura que deseo tener al final)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resultado, espero obtener 20 nuevos .csv donde se vean las columnas de mes, hora, percentil 0.05, percentil 0.5 y percentil 0.95. Es decir, similar a la estructura anterior pero con las columnas de los percentiles para cada hora de cada mes.

Adjunto el código que llevaba, en caso de que pueda servir de guía, base o para recibir correcciones. Claramente, no me funciona jaja.

Adjunto carpeta con los .csv: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17HaJ2q9SZgbI7B9oG5oue9Vi_7HZvHD3?usp=sharing

Quedo atento y muchas gracias de antemano.

```
library(tidyverse)
#Seleccionar directorio de trabajo

setwd("G:/IDEAM-2019-09-04/Recuentos/Estaciones Seleccionadas/TEMPS1NEW")
list.files(pattern='*.csv') %>%

  # Leemos cada csv en un único data.frame y la agrupación por archivo
  map_df(function(x) read_csv(x) %>% mutate(filename=gsub('.csv', '', basename(x)))) %>%

  #separación de los meses

  separate(event_time, into = c("fecha", "nodat"), sep = " ") %>%
  separate(fecha, into = c("año", "mes", "dia"), sep = "-") %>%

  # Genero los grupos para el cálculo de los percentiles .05, .5 y .95
  group_by(filename, mes,hora) %>%

  quantile(probs=seq(.05, .5, .95)) %>%


  group_by(filename) %>%
  # Dividimos el único data frame en cada estación met
  nest(-filename) %>%

  # Guardado de cada división en un nuevo .csv
  pwalk(function(filename, data) write.csv(data, 
                                           paste0(file.path("../Percentiles/TEMPS1/", filename), ".csv"),
                                           quote = TRUE,
                                           row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Sin los datos propiamente dichos no es fácil reproducir el problema y ofrecer una solución. De todos modos me llama la atención la línea `quantile(probs=seq(.05, .5, .95))`. Por `help("quantile")` esta función recibe como datos un vector y lo que le está pasando la tubería desde el lado izquierdo es un data.frame. Esa parte del código está fallando.

Comment: Hola @mpaladino Perdón la tardanza en responder. Ya he agregado a la publicación un enlace a una carpeta drive que contiene todos los datos de una de las carpetas que estoy trabajando (todas son iguales, excepto en la cantidad de .csv que tienen)

Quedo atento a una nueva respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes algunos problemas en la forma en que quieres calcular los cuantiles:

1. Según entiendo, buscas los cuantiles 0.05, 0.5 y .95, sin embargo eso no es lo que estarías haciendo con `seq(.05, .5, .95)` ya que esta función te estaría generando una sequencia desde .05 a .5 en un paso de .95, es decir el resultado es el primer valor (0.05), si los cuantiles que buscas son los que menciono arriba, simplemente los indicas de esta forma `probs = c(.05, .5, .95)`.
2. El otro problema que ya te mencionó @mpaladino es que no estás indicando correctamente sobre que datos vas a hacer el calculo, así como está, estarías pasando el `data.frame` completo, entiendo que en realidad deberías pasar en todo caso la columna sobre la que aplicarás la función, imagino que es `event_value`
3. Pero, aún resolviendo esto, hay un problema, en este caso `quantile()` retornaría tres valores cuando en realidad, el flujo estaría esperando uno solo. Con lo cual, deberías reformular esta función además que te estaría faltando un detalle importante, si tu idea es construir un total por cada grupo, es necesario usar `summarize()`. La idea entonces podría ser algo así (esto es un ejemplo)

   a. Construyendo las nuevas columnas haciendo que quantile retorne un valor por vez

   ```
   mtcars %>% 
       group_by(cyl) %>% 
       summarise(mean.05 = quantile(disp, probs = 0.05),
                 mean.5 = quantile(disp, probs = 0.5),
                 mean.95 = quantile(disp, probs = 0.95))
   ```

   b. Calculando las tres columnas a la vez

   ```
   mtcars %>% 
       group_by(cyl) %>% 
       do(data.frame(t(quantile(.$disp, probs = c(.05, .5, .95)))))
   ```

Comment: Hola @Patricio Moracho. Ya adjunté una carpeta drive con los datos, en caso de que te sirva para crear una solución.

Revisaré lo que me acabas de mencionar y comentaré posteriormente. Quedo atento a cualquier nueva ayuda que generes con los datos que ya adjunté.

Gracias!